# Another DropDownList selected item problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am really confused about ASP.Net MVC (2.0 RC) DropDownList. It doesn't seem to accept my selected item.

Here is my SelectListItem list (it is created inside loop. Selected being boolean)

```
savingTypesList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = selected, Text = type.Name, Value = "" + type.SavingTypeId });
```

Creating SelectList itself..

```
return new SelectList(savingTypesList, "Value", "Text", (string)selected);
```

And my View..

```
<p>
    <label for="SavingType">Saving type</label>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("SavingType", Model.SavingType, "-- select a parameter saving type --", "")%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("SavingType", "*")%>
</p>
```

When I check details of the returned SelectList it show me following information

[alt text http://www.tx3.fi/selected.PNG](http://www.tx3.fi/selected.PNG)

As you can see SelectedValue is set correctly and it matches to the item in the Items array. When I check the actual generated HTML there isn't any selected. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem on my own.

As you can see on my View I had DropDownList with name "SavingType" and it was binded to the Model.SavingType. Everything works fine except the selected value. Only thing I did was that I changed the name of the dropdownlist (and of course links to it like label for="SavingTypeList")

Answer (score 0):

This issue was started from MVC 1.0 at least.

**Problem:** when DropDownList Name has same value as name of object binded to it, selected option will be not selected in result.

**Solution:** Name binded object different, Model.SavingTypeList for example in your case.
Renaming DDL Name is not preferred, because you may loose your binding after form submitting.